# How do I annotate the type of a parameter of an abstractmethod, when the parameter can have any type derived from a specific base type?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, mypy, python-3.8, python-typing

How do I annotate the type of a function parameter of a abstractmethod, when the parameter can have any type derived from a specific base type?

Example:

```py
import abc
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class BaseConfig(abc.ABC):
    option_base: str

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class ConfigA(BaseConfig):
    option_a: str

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class ConfigB(BaseConfig):
    option_b: bool


class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, config: BaseConfig):
        pass

class ClassA(Base):
    def do_something(self, config: ConfigA):
        # test.py:27: error: Argument 1 of "do_something" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "BaseConfig"
        print("option_a: " + config.option_a)

class ClassB(Base):
    def do_something(self, config: ConfigB):
        # test.py:33: error: Argument 1 of "do_something" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "BaseConfig"
        print("option_b: " + str(config.option_b))

conf_a = ConfigA(option_a="value_a", option_base="value_base")
conf_b = ConfigB(option_b=True, option_base="value_base")
object_a = ClassA()
object_b = ClassB()
object_a.do_something(conf_a)
object_b.do_something(conf_b)
```

When parsing this with mypy I get

```
test.py:27: error: Argument 1 of "do_something" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "BaseConfig"
test.py:33: error: Argument 1 of "do_something" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "BaseConfig"
```

How would I need to change the signature of Base.do_something() so mypy doesn't report any error, while still enforcing, that the function parameter of the abstract method do_something is derived from BaseConfig?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TLDR: Make the baseclass `Generic` and parameterise the type of configuration:

```
C = TypeVar('C', bound=BaseConfig)

class Base(abc.ABC, Generic[C]):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, config: C):
        pass
```

---

The original class hierarchy declares that `ClassA` can be used anywhere `Base` is valid. When we assume some variable `obj: Base`, this leads to a conflict:

- We can assign `obj = ClassA()` since `ClassA` "is a" `Base` class.
- We can use `obj.do_something(BaseConfig())` since `obj` "is a" `Base` instance.

However, `ClassA.do_something(config: ConfigA)` says we cannot do both *at the same time*, contradicting the type equivalence.

---

Instead, we need to distinguish between "`Base` that takes a `ConfigA`", "`Base` that takes a `ConfigB`" and so on. This is done by parameterising `Base` with a type-variable for the config.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

C = TypeVar('C', bound=BaseConfig)      # C "is some" BaseConfig type

class Base(abc.ABC, Generic[C]):        # class takes type variable ...
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, config: C):  # ... and uses it in method signature
        pass
```

This allows us to have both generic and concrete `Base` variants - for example, `Base[ConfigA]` is a "`Base` that takes a `ConfigA`". From this, the subclasses can be derived as taking the appropriate configuration:

```
class ClassA(Base[ConfigA]):        # set type variable to ConfigA
    def do_something(self, config: ConfigA):
        print("option_a: " + config.option_a)
```