# Typing inheritence for class properties in Python

Tags: python

First, please take a look at the following code:

```py
from typing import Type


class C:
    @staticmethod
    def c_fun():
        return 23


class C1(C):
    @staticmethod
    def c1_fun():
        return 42


class M:
    def __init__(self, c: Type[C]):
        self.c = c()


class M1(M):
    def __init__(self, c: Type[C1]):
        super().__init__(c=c)
        # self.c = c()

    def m1_fun(self):
        print(self.c.c1_fun())

    def show_type(self):
        print(type(self.c))


M1(c=C1).m1_fun()  # Output: 42
M1(c=C1).show_type()  # Output: <class '__main__.C1'>
```

The code compiles and works as intended without any errors. However, the Python linter in PyCharm displays the following warning when referring to `self.c.c1_fun()` in M1.m1_fun():

`Unresolved attribute reference 'c1_fun' for class 'C'`

although it seems to resolve during compilation. To ensure the typing of `self.c`, I print it out, and it seems to be C1 during compilation as intended.

When I uncomment `self.c = c()` in M1.__init__() the linter warning disappears - but I would like to avoid repetitiveness, as it is already done in the constructor of class M.

My questions:

1. Am I doing anything wrong, as the PyCharm linter proclaims?
2. Is there any good practice to do it without repetition of assignments?

**Edit:**
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167179/how-do-i-annotate-the-type-of-a-parameter-of-an-abstractmethod-when-the-paramet) - it seems like that using Generic is the way to go (as it was done in the chosen answer for the current post).

Comment: It's a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principe. An instance of `M1` could be assigned to a variable `x : M`, but then I should be able to assume that `x.__init__` can receive any value of type `C`, but `M1.__init__` is restricted to values of type `C1`.

Comment: I understand, so how can I implement the same code in such a way that doesn't violate LSP?

Comment: I don't think the LSP allows you to use inheritance like this at all. You would have to use composition instead, making `M1` *wrap* an instance of `M` that used `C1` instead of `C`.

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue is the difference between subtyping and subclassing.

Comment: @chepner In reality, I made M and C as abstract classes (interfaces) as basic structures for C1....C_n and M1...M_n sub-classes - so they can't really be instantiated. What would you suggest then?

Comment: Abstract base classes are implemented as a run-time check; it's not something the static typechecker can make use of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by having `M` be a `Generic` type, which allows a subclass (or for that matter a specific instance of the superclass) to narrow the type of `c`.

```
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar


class C:
    @staticmethod
    def c_fun() -> int:
        return 23


class C1(C):
    @staticmethod
    def c1_fun() -> int:
        return 42


_CType = TypeVar('_CType', bound=C)


class M(Generic[_CType]):
    def __init__(self, c: Type[_CType]) -> None:
        self.c = c()


class M1(M[C1]):
    def __init__(self, c: Type[C1]) -> None:
        super().__init__(c=c)

    def m1_fun(self) -> None:
        print(self.c.c1_fun())

    def show_type(self) -> None:
        print(type(self.c))


M1(c=C1).m1_fun()  # Output: 42
M1(c=C1).show_type()  # Output: <class '__main__.C1'>
```

Comment: Just to note, this appeases the type checker, but still violates the LSP: `x: List[M] = [M(C), M1(C1)]; x[1].__init__(C)`. (Yes, calling `__init__` explicitly isn't something you should do on an already initialized object, but the type checker can't assume that won't happen.)

Comment: @chepner that code produces a type checking error (at least with `mypy`): `Cannot access "__init__" directly`.  They're two steps ahead of you!  :)  Presumably this is a thing that causes enough problems for static type checking that mypy just says "don't do that".

Comment: @Samwise Do you agree with the statement that it violates the LSP though? 
I'll try to be more specific - each M_i (i=1...N) (which is inherited from M) should instantiate its appropriate C_i (which is inherited from C). They can't be mixed (e.g. by using M1 with C2), and the parent C serves only as an interface/abstract for C_i. 
Is there any other way to implement C_i without violating the LSP?

Comment: `M1[C1]` is not a subtype of `M[C]`.  (I don't think.)