# `mypy` doesn't recognize inherited dataclass members

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to design my code as follows - i.e., I'd like that each subclass which implements my functionlity will have as member a collection of fields, which can also inherit from a base dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

@dataclass
class BaseFields:
    pass


@dataclass
class MoreFields(baseFields):
    name: str = "john"


class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.fields: BaseFields = BaseFields()
        
    @abstractmethod
    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        pass
    

class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.fields = MoreFields()

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        print(f"Hi {self.fields.name}!")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.say_hi()
```

When I run it, I get `Hi john!` as output, as expected.
But `mypy` doesn't seem to recognize it:

```
❯ mypy dataclass_inheritence.py
dataclass_inheritence.py:25: error: "baseFields" has no attribute "name"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I looked and found [this github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5384), and it links to another one, but doesn't seem like it offers a solution.

I should also note that if I remove the `@dataclass` decorators and implement the `Fields` classes as plain ol' classes, with `__init__`  - I still get the same `mypy` error.

My motivation (as you may tell) is to reference composite members within the implemented methods of the functional subclasses. Those members are constants, as in the example, so I might use some form of [Enum inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679930/how-to-extend-python-enum), but looking at this question it's not a popular design choice (will have to use some 3rd party module which I'm not keen on doing).

Has anyone encountered something similar? Do you have suggestions for a design that could achieve my goal?

Comment: ``self.fields: baseFields`` explicitly tells MyPy to *only* expect the baseclass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I annotate the type of a parameter of an abstractmethod, when the parameter can have any type derived from a specific base type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167179/how-do-i-annotate-the-type-of-a-parameter-of-an-abstractmethod-when-the-paramet)

Comment: please, use CapitalCase for class names.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `self.fields` is declared as `baseFields` in `A.__init__`, and is not narrowed implicitly by assigning a `moreFields` to it in `B.__init__` -- after all, you might want to be able to re-assign it to another `baseFields` instance, and it is therefore never assumed to be anything more specific than `baseFields`.

If you *explicitly* annotate it as `moreFields` in `B.__init__`, the error goes away:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.fields: moreFields = moreFields()

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        print(f"Hi {self.fields.name}!")  # ok!
```

although this actually feels like a bug in `mypy`, because now you can do *this*, violating the LSP:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b: A = B()
    b.fields = baseFields()  # no mypy error, because b is an A, right?
    b.say_hi()  # runtime AttributeError because b is actually a B!
```

If I want a subclass to be able to narrow the type of an attribute, I make it a property backed by private attributes:

```
class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__baseFields = baseFields()
        
    @property
    def fields(self) -> baseFields:
        return self.__baseFields

    @abstractmethod
    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        pass
    

class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__moreFields = moreFields()

    @property
    def fields(self) -> moreFields:
        return self.__moreFields

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        print(f"Hi {self.fields.name}!")  # ok!
```

Comment: Seems like it could work in my case, and I assume (will try soon) the inheritance is preserved, i.e. if `baseFields` had members I could access them as well, right?

Comment: That's orthogonal to the question of how the inheritance between `A` and `B` works (which is really what your question is about), but yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic base class to define the class. I would also have the `fields` attribute be passed to the base class constructor. There are some subtle tricks to get the signature on the init method working, but this should work.

Some imports you'll want:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, overload
```

Rename the classes with more pythonic names, and define a generic TypeVar to represent which fields we are using.

```
@dataclass
class BaseFields:
    pass


@dataclass
class MoreFields(BaseFields):
    name: str = "john"


Fields = TypeVar('Fields', bound=BaseFields)
```

For defining the base class, we want to allow the fields param to be anything satisfying the TypeVar. We also need to add some overloads to handle the case where a default is used or not.

```
class A(Generic[Fields], ABC):
    fields: Fields

    @overload
    def __init__(self: A[BaseFields]) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: A[Fields], fields: Fields) -> None:
        ...

    def __init__(self, fields=None):
        self.fields = fields or BaseFields()

    @abstractmethod
    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Now we can run our test:

```
class B(A[MoreFields]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(MoreFields())

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        print(f"Hi {self.fields.name}!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.say_hi()
```

```
$ mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```